# Python HTML source code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to write a script that picks a special point from the source code and returns it. (print it)

```
import urllib.request                           

Webseite = "http://myip.is/"                    
html_code = urllib.request.urlopen(Webseite)

print(html_code.read().decode('ISO-8859-1'))
```

This is my current code.
I would like to print only the IP address that the website gives.
The input of this I will print in python (title="copy ip address").

Comment: if you want to parse HTML to retrieve any kind of data, then use BeautifulSoup library

Comment: @mic4ael's suggestion is for sure good! In this simple special case, you might be already served with split once on `address">` take the element 1 of that list and split one last time that string on `</a>` and pick element 0 which should be the IP ... more elegant should be the beautiful soup ...

Comment: Thanks mic4ael for the tip with BeautifulSoup!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get('http://myip.is/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html5lib")
myIP = mySoup.find('a', {'title': 'copy ip address'}).text
print(myIP)
```

This uses the requests library (which you should always use for HTTP requests) to pull the page, feeds the content to BeautifulSoup, a very nice HTML parser, and asks BeautifulSoup to find a single `<a>` tag, with the atrtibuet `title` set to 'copy ip address', and then save the text component of that tag as `myIP`.

Comment: Perfect!
This was exactly what im looking at.

Comment: You may have been mistaken.

Comment: myIP = mySoup.find #is false
myIP = soup.find # is right

Comment: Ha, just goes to show, always test your code before posting to stackexchange. I did not :P

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jsonip](http://jsonip.com) which returns a JSON object that you can easily parse using standard Python library

```
import json
from urllib2 import urlopen

my_ip = json.load(urlopen('http://jsonip.com'))['ip']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to find the IP addresses:

```
import urllib.request
import re

Webseite = "http://myip.is/"
html_code = urllib.request.urlopen(Webseite)

content = html_code.read().decode('ISO-8859-1')
ip_regex = r'(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}'

ips_found = re.findall(ip_regex, content)
print(ips_found[0])
```